# Which artifactory should I choose for my project?

Tags: android, maven, artifactory

I have my android app already finished with different components. Now I plan to reuse for reskining in future again. Please help me to choose which **Artifactory Edition** is best option for me. My app is based on Maven.

I will be the only one working on it and from one system. So don't think enterprise one is correct for this app.

Link to [Artifactory Edition](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix)

Comment: Requests for libraries and tools are off topic here.  As are opinion based questions.

Comment: Hmm.. okay. I am looking which edition is best when your app is broken into component and each component need to be deployed to run app. And I will be reskining a lot in future. So will there be any issue with pro version for uploading more app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between Artifactory Pro and Artifactory Enterprise is listed on the page linked [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix)

Now the main difference between the Pro and Enterprise is that the Pro does not include Support from JFrog but only upgrades and bug fixes.
With your scale, I will not get into the additional advantages of the Enterprise as it won't make a difference.

I hope that this is what you need :)

Comment: Thanks @Ariel for your answer